# creating and writing file in worker role

Tags: azure-worker-roles

i m writing below code to create and write text file c drive for worker role.
it works fine on my local machine but fails on the cloud service

```
 public override void Run()
    {
       //  This is a sample worker implementation. Replace with your logic.
        Trace.TraceInformation("Trail entry point called", "Information");

        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                TextWriter tsw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Hello.txt", true);
                tsw.WriteLine("Hi DA Testesting");
                tsw.Close();                    
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                Trace.TraceInformation("Working", "Information");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TextWriter tsw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Hello.txt", true);
            tsw.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            tsw.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What failure are you seeing?

Comment: it fails to create the txt file in c drive i have used the local resource to overcome this problem